# How to get the settings from the toolbar

Tags: magento-1.9

Customers can set settings to show products using the toolbar:

[image: toolbar]

But how do I get the selected settings, like what `pageSize` they want?

**EDIT:**
Sorry for not being clear enough, I'm trying to get the by te customer selected `pageSize` in PHP. Because I load the products myself and I want to use the selected amount of products.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look in **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php**
And found a lot of public functions to get the settings.

This is how I get the `pageSize`:

```
$testObject = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar();
$pageSizeLimit = $testObject->getLimit();
print_r($pageSizeLimit);
```